# Trouble installing Symfony3. Virtualbox - Ubuntu guest / Windows 10 host

Tags: php, ubuntu, virtualbox, symfony

I've been trying to install Symfony3 into Ubuntu 14.04 running in virtualbox and have been following this tutorial:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/setup.html

So far I can get the Symfony command installed.  I try running the Symfony command to create an application under the `/var/www/html/` folder - my Apache web directory - and the following error is thrown :

[image]

I want to set up my application in this folder as this is a shared folder to a Windows 10 host.   I can install Symfony under my home directory and can access this from the host browser.

Personally I think it's a permissions issue.  I did find this [this page](http://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/file_permissions.html) for help and did not get much success.  Can someone enlighten me as to what's going on?

Answer (score 0):

Did you run this command already:

```
HTTPDUSER=`ps axo user,comm | grep -E '[a]pache|[h]ttpd|[_]www|[w]ww-data|[n]ginx' | grep -v root | head -1 | cut -d\  -f1`
sudo setfacl -R -m u:"$HTTPDUSER":rwX -m u:`whoami`:rwX var
sudo setfacl -dR -m u:"$HTTPDUSER":rwX -m u:`whoami`:rwX var
```

Run it under the `/var/www/html/symfony_test` directory and tell us the results.

Answer (score 0):

You have no write permissions because `/var/www` folders are writable by apache user. In some case (often linux) apache user is `wwwdata`. In MacOs the user is `_www`.

You can also try with some trick. First one, is to avoid apache for your development: just install symfony in you `~/Development` folder, and run `./bin/console server:run` command. Symfony allow you to run the php builtin server.